# Object.assign() doesn't structure my array of objects the way it is

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

[image: My array of objects called Favoritecoins]

```
if (!this.favoriteCoins.some(e => e.cryptoName === coinId)) {

     Object.assign(this.favoriteCoins, {cryptoName: coinId})

}
```

The image is the result of my Object.assign and I wanted to know why doesn't it assign the way all the others are structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Object.assign` and passing an array as an argument.  Array's can still accept properties the same ways objects do.  But if you want to add the object to the array, use `Array.prototype.push` instead.

```
if (!this.favoriteCoins.some(e => e.cryptoName === coinId)) {

     this.favoriteCoins.push({cryptoName: coinId})

}
```